# Can I write "inspector takes a sample of vials" ("sample" with countable nouns)

Tags: word-usage

> After the vial crimping operation, the Quality Control inspector takes **a sample** of vials for leak-testing.

The meaning is: the inspector collects from one to several vials from the batch in order to perform a leak test. But can one use the word **sample** here, or is it only used with noncount nouns such as blood, powder, etc.?

Comment: I would not use take a sample here as it can be confused with other things. I would say: **takes or uses several vials as samples to perform a leak test.** Take a sample is very much associated with liquid of many kinds. A blood sample, an urine sample, a x sample.

Comment: You can also say: *The inspector performs leak-testing upon **a sampling** of vials.* or *...takes **a sampling** of vials for leak-testing* (which only *implies* that he performs that test).

Comment: "Sampling of" means taking a sample of. So, I would not use that personally.

Comment: @Lambie. You may well be correct about common or medical usage, but you are quite wrong about the technical usage in statistics and quality control. According to Wolfram, a sample is defined as **a subset of a population ... obtained ... for the purposes of investigating the properties of the underlying parent population.** As I note in my answer, the world is replete with references to samples of voters or of consumers. In fact, statistical sampling depends on the countability of the population.

Comment: http://www.alpsleak.com/one-step-isbm Bottles and vials would use the same lingo. I don't see any samples. They test actual bottles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to use "sample" only with mass nouns. You will read in the newspapers frequently about a "random sample of registered voters."